# Issues with resubmitting a form using click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've run into something interesting and I'm a bit stumped with this.

Basically I have a form:

```
<form>   
    <div class="formWrapper">
        <span>Refine your search</span>
        <input type="text">
            <select>
                <option>English</option>
                <option>French</option>
                <option>Dutch</option>
            </select>
        <button class="submitButton" type="submit" data-ajaxurl="http://localhost/_myFile.html" data-ajaxtarget="#myFile_search" >Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and some bootstrap pagination links:

```
<div class="bootstrap_pagination">
    <ul>     
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#" data-number = "1" onclick="clicked_bootstrap_pagination(this, event)">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-number = "2" onclick="clicked_bootstrap_pagination(this, event)">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-number = "3" onclick="clicked_bootstrap_pagination(this, event)">3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-number = "4" onclick="clicked_bootstrap_pagination(this, event)">4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-number = "5" onclick="clicked_bootstrap_pagination(this, event)">5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="plain">
            <a href="#">&rsaquo;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="plain">
            <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Somewhere on the page I have a hidden field as well, storing the data-number of the pagination link I clicked on, the default value is 1: `<input type="hidden" name="number" value="1">`

And this is the function that takes care of the clicked pagination link:

```
function clicked_bootstrap_pagination(clickedLink, event){
        event.preventDefault();     
        $this = $(clickedLink); 
        var pageNumberValue = $this.data("number");//get number
        var $hiddenField = $("#drivers_initial form input[name='number']");//hidden field   
        $hiddenField.val(pageNumberValue);//update value of hidden field
        $('form .formWrapper button.submitButton').click();//resubmits the form             
    }
```

When I click on a pagination link, the function runs it updates the data-number in the hidden input field and resubmit the form, pretty simple.

OK, so here is the problem: when the submit button is clicked on - my search button in the form - I also want to run another function, `resetHiddenFieldNumber()`,

but the problem is, as you've probably already gathered, that that function will also run when the pagination link is clicked on because of this line`$('form .formWrapper button.submitButton').click();//resubmits the form`, and I don't want that, I just want to be able to run `resetHiddenFieldNumber()` only when I click the submit button
I tried a couple of things, among those, an onclick attribute in the submit button:

`<button class="submitButton" type="submit" data-ajaxurl="http://localhost/_myFile.html" data-ajaxtarget="#myFile_search" onclick="resetHiddenFieldNumber()">Search</button>`

but, with this approach, as said and expected the function runs also when the the pagination link is clicked on because in `clicked_bootstrap_pagination()` I'm resubmitting the form.
I've hoped that I could somehow distinguish between the pagination link and the button after this line executed `$('form .formWrapper button.submitButton').click();//resubmits the form` but of course I can't.

The problem is the fact that, from what I understand, the line that resubmits the form effectively forces a click on the submit button even if you don't actually click on it.

I tried to use `submit()` but the whole page reloads and that's not desirable.

Does anybody have an idea how I could run a function only when I click on the submit button?

I hope it's all clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to pass some data to http://localhost/_myFile.html you don't always need to use from-submit way. You can just have on-click event for submitting the data to the server without any page reload.

```
<div class="formWrapper">
        <span>Refine your search</span>
        <input type="text">
            <select id="language-selection">
                <option>English</option>
                <option>French</option>
                <option>Dutch</option>
            </select>
        <button class="not-submit-button" id="send-request-button" type="button" data-ajaxtarget="#myFile_search" >Search</button>
    </div>
```

and then do following event handler

```
  //js code
    $('#send-request-button').click(function(){
   //on button click
    var data = $('#language-selection').val();
     //collect value of the select
       //send request 
       $.get('http://localhost/_myFile.html', data, function(response){
          //refresh you UI
       })
    })
```